# Play only one video at a time HTML5

Tags: html, video

I'm using below code to play only one video at a time but it is not working properly. Please suggest.

```
document.getElementById("vid1").addEventListener('play', dimBack1, false);
document.getElementById("vid2").addEventListener('play', dimBack2, false);
document.getElementById("vid3").addEventListener('play', dimBack3, false);
document.getElementById("vid4").addEventListener('play', dimBack4, false);
document.getElementById("vid5").addEventListener('play', dimBack5, false);
document.getElementById("vid6").addEventListener('play', dimBack6, false);


function dimBack1() {
document.getElementById("vid2").pause();
document.getElementById("vid3").pause();
document.getElementById("vid4").pause();
document.getElementById("vid5").pause();
document.getElementById("vid6").pause();
document.getElementById("vid1").play();
}
function dimBack2() {
document.getElementById("vid1").pause();
document.getElementById("vid3").pause();
document.getElementById("vid4").pause();
document.getElementById("vid5").pause();
document.getElementById("vid6").pause();
document.getElementById("vid2").play();
}
function dimBack3() {
document.getElementById("vid3").play();
document.getElementById("vid1").pause();
document.getElementById("vid2").pause();
document.getElementById("vid4").pause();
document.getElementById("vid5").pause();
document.getElementById("vid6").pause();
}
function dimBack4() {
document.getElementById("vid4").play();
document.getElementById("vid1").pause();
document.getElementById("vid2").pause();
document.getElementById("vid3").pause();
document.getElementById("vid5").pause();
document.getElementById("vid6").pause();
}
function dimBack5() {
document.getElementById("vid5").play();
document.getElementById("vid1").pause();
document.getElementById("vid2").pause();
document.getElementById("vid3").pause();
document.getElementById("vid4").pause();
document.getElementById("vid6").pause();
}
function dimBack6() {
document.getElementById("vid6").play();
document.getElementById("vid1").pause();
document.getElementById("vid2").pause();
document.getElementById("vid3").pause();
document.getElementById("vid4").pause();
document.getElementById("vid5").pause();
}
</script>
```

The above code is live online at http://www.confesstalk.com/cl/test.html

**Main reequirement:**

1. allow videos to load
2. click first video
3. click second video
4. on clicking first video, pause first video.
5. if i click another video i need code to pause second video

Comment: it works fine for me... (Firefox 30) What is it not working properly for you exactly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few "plays" added in different order.

There really is no need to use `.play();` with `.addEventListener('play', ...)`, as this may cause a "loop" in "events".

Use `array` to run events in elements, see:

```
(function () {
    var videos = [
        document.getElementById("vid1"),
        document.getElementById("vid2"),
        document.getElementById("vid3"),
        document.getElementById("vid4"),
        document.getElementById("vid5"),
        document.getElementById("vid6")
    ];

    function stopOthers () {
        var id = this.id, i = 0;
        for (var j = videos.length; i < j; i++) {
            if (videos[i].id !== id) {
                videos[i].pause();
            }
        }
    }

    var i = 0;
    for (var j = videos.length; i < j; i++) {
        videos[i].addEventListener("play", stopOthers, false);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a `for of` version for all the people who can't read the `for` loops, like me. ;)

```js
//Get all videos with the class "video-single-play"
let allVideos = document.querySelectorAll(".video-single-play video");
    
// Function for stopping the other videos
function stopOtherVideos(clickedIndex) {
  for (let [i, video] of allVideos.entries()) {
    if (i !== clickedIndex) {
      video.pause();
    }
  }
}

//Loop over all videos to get their index and attach an event listener
for (let [i, video] of allVideos.entries()) {
  let clickedIndex = i;
  video.addEventListener("play", function() {
    stopOtherVideos(clickedIndex);
  });
}
```

Two other changes to the original answer:

For the for of loop to give you the index and the element itself you need to use restructuring (`[i, video]`) and Array.prototype.entries(). Here it is explained in more detail: [access to es6 array element index inside for-of loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348937/access-to-es6-array-element-index-inside-for-of-loop)

For me, the event listener executed immediately when it was bound. To prevent that I wrapped the stopOtherVideos function into another function. Here it is explained in more detail: [addeventlistenerclick firing immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667267/addeventlistenerclick-firing-immediately)