# Access to ES6 array element index inside for-of loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, for-of-loop

We can access array elements using a for-of loop:

```js
for (const j of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) {
  console.log(j);
}
```

How can I modify this code to access the current index too? I want to achieve this using for-of syntax, neither forEach nor for-in.

Answer (score 707, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys):

```js
for (const index of ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"].keys()) {
  console.log(index);
}
```

If you want to access both the key and the value, you can use [`Array.prototype.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
for (const [index, value] of ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"].entries()) {
  console.log(index, value);
}
```

Comment: In case someone wonders, I tested `for-of` with `.entries()` and it's twice as slow compared to `.forEach()`. https://jsperf.com/for-of-vs-foreach-with-index

Comment: @K48 nice to know, use "reversed for-loop" if you want to have the fastest in es: https://www.incredible-web.com/blog/performance-of-for-loops-with-javascript/

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to yield from inside a nested loop. Can't use forEach, because the function creates scope problems for the `yield` keyword. But I need access to the index for my use case, so... basic old `;;` loop it is, I guess.

Comment: @KyleBaker And what's wrong with a for-of loop with `.entires()`?

Comment: I presume it would also not be performant, but it certainly wouldn't be necessary. You can use it if you like, but the nature of a standard for loop is that one has 'access' to both the index and value in a very straightforward manner. With a for-of, one would _need_ `.entries()` to have access to the index.

Comment: Instead reverse loop you may cache length https://jsperf.com/reverse-loop-vs-cache.
For-of usefull for iterable processing when you able to process stream without creating big arrays in RAM. Loop speed wouldn't be bottleneck since you will have I/O latency in such cases.

Comment: Does it work even though we're cycling an HTMLCollection?

Comment: @Rickyx You can always convert HTMLCollection into array. In ES6 it is done with `Array.from(myHtmlCollection)`, in older notations `Array.prototype.slice.call( htmlCollection )`. Then you can call `.entries()` on the array.

Comment: For me, it's all about readabilty, so this wins even if the performance is not the best. For servers just buy a stronger one, and for browsers - why do you do such intensive logic on the user's side?!

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski both the entries() and keys() iterators return all indices from minimum to maximum including those that have not been set in a sparse array, so using for .. of with those won't help.

Answer (score 407):

[`Array#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) returns the index and the value, if you need both:

```
for (let [index, value] of array.entries()) {

}
```

Comment: With TypeScript: 'TS2495: Type IterableIterator is not an array type or a string type'. Seems like this will be solved: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12346

Comment: Also Internet Explorer not supported.

Comment: Not nice. Throws an error e.g. with `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules.entries()` or even `document.styleSheets.entries()` and probably many other DOM iterable structures. Still have to use `_.forEach()` from `lodash`

Comment: @Steven: If you don't need the index, you can just do `for (var value of document.styleSheets) {}`. If you do need the index you can convert the value to an array first via `Array.from`: `for (let [index, value] of Array.from(document.styleSheets)) {}`.

Comment: That's nice! `Array.from` is FTW

Comment: Instead of complaining about which browsers support what, write in ES6 and transpile down to ES5.  Write once, DRY, KISS...

Comment: But entries() does not skip over the unset entries in a sparse array, like forEach() does.

Answer (score 137):

In this world of flashy new native functions, we sometimes forget the basics.

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log('index:', i, 'element:', arr[i]);
}
```

Clean, efficient, and you can still `break` the loop. Bonus! You can also start from the end and go backwards with `i--`!

Additional note: If you're using the value a lot within the loop, you may wish to do `const value = arr[i];` at the top of the loop for an easy, readable reference.

Comment: Yep. Good one, clear and simple. Oh, and like that you have a super easy way to access the key/index of the array.

Comment: By the way the condition should look like this -> for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
without the (-1) or it will not loop throughout all the elements of the array.

Comment: @Combine Good catch! I have updated my answer to reflect your note.

Comment: You can still `break` a `for-of` and `for (let [index, value] of array.entries())` is far easier to read. Going backwards is as easy as adding `.reverse()`.

Comment: This does not answer the question in any way.
It would be nice in a comment (basics are always important), but not here.

Comment: I don't think this answers the particular question, but you are completely right that this is a good way to do it.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly acceptable answer to this question. It will never be the accepted answer but it has helped a few dozen people or more who have searched for this question. This is what SO is for.

Comment: The simple `for` loop is ~8 times faster than the `for of array.entries()`.

https://jsbench.me/6dkh13vqrr/1

Comment: This will be highly inefficient for a sparse array.

Comment: @lawrence-witt no! for `;;` is work with async await code

Comment: @KhanifIkhsanudin yep you're totally right, not sure why I commented that!

Answer (score 25):

In a `for..of` loop we can achieve this via `array.entries()`. `array.entries` returns a new Array iterator object. An iterator object knows how to access items from an iterable one at the time, while keeping track of its current position within that sequence.

When the `next()` method is called on the iterator key value pairs are generated. In these key value pairs the array **index** is the key and the array item is the value.

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let iterator = arr.entries();
console.log(iterator.next().value); // [0, 'a']
console.log(iterator.next().value); // [1, 'b']
```

A `for..of` loop is basically a construct which consumes an iterable and loops through all elements (using an iterator under the hood). We can combine this with `array.entries()` in the following manner:

```js
array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for (let indexValue of array.entries()) {
  console.log(indexValue);
}


// we can use array destructuring to conveniently
// store the index and value in variables
for (let [index, value] of array.entries()) {
   console.log(index, value);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also handle index yourself if You need the **index**, it will not work if You need the **key**.

```
let i = 0;
for (const item of iterableItems) {
  // do something with index
  console.log(i);

  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another approach could be using `Array.prototype.forEach()` as

```js
Array.from({
  length: 5
}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)).forEach((val, index) => {
  console.log(val, index)
})
```

Answer (score 4):

in html/js context, on modern browsers, with other iterable objects than Arrays we could also use [Iterable].entries():

```
for(let [index, element] of document.querySelectorAll('div').entries()) {

    element.innerHTML = '#' + index

}
```

Comment: Yes this works, whereas other mentioned above by @Steven Pribilinskiy other DOM methods return objects that don't have an `entries` method for them.

Answer (score 4):

Just create a variable before the loop and assign an integer value.

`let index = 0;`

and then use [addition assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment) into the loop scope

`index += 1;`

That's It, check the below snippet example.

```js
let index = 0;
for (const j of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) {
  console.log('index ',index);
  index += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For those using objects that are not an `Array` or even array-like, you can build your own iterable easily so you can still use `for of` for things like `localStorage` which really only have a `length`:

```js
function indexerator(length) {
    var output = new Object();
    var index = 0;
    output[Symbol.iterator] = function() {
        return {next:function() {
            return (index < length) ? {value:index++} : {done:true};
        }};
    };
    return output;
}
```

Then just feed it a number:

```js
for (let index of indexerator(localStorage.length))
    console.log(localStorage.key(index))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try making use of indexOf menthod inside for of... loop

```js
let arrData = [15, 64, 78]
for (const data of arrData) {
  console.log("data value", data, "index of data ", arrData.indexOf(data));
}
```

Comment: This works only on unique elements, and has `O(n^2)` complexity :(

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use JavaScript to solve your problem

```js
iterate(item, index) {
    console.log(`${item} has index ${index}`);
    //Do what you want...
}

readJsonList() {    
    jsonList.forEach(this.iterate);
    //it could be any array list.
}
```

Answer (score -3):

es6 `for...in`

```
for(const index in [15, 64, 78]) {                        
    console.log(index);
}
```

Comment: The question is asking about a `for...of` loop not a `for...in`

Comment: `for...in` is part of the original ECMAScript specification (i.e."es1") . Also, note that `for...in` is meant for iterating over object properties. While it can iterate over arrays, it may not do so in the expected order. See more in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: this is a good answer for the aim of the question. Which is about "array" itteration.

Comment: no it's not a good answer, since the question was specific about `for...of` loop and not just general itteration...