# TypeScript for ... of with index / key?

Tags: for-loop, foreach, typescript

As described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) TypeScript introduces a foreach loop:

```
var someArray = [9, 2, 5];
for (var item of someArray) {
    console.log(item); // 9,2,5
}
```

But isn't there any index/key? I would expect something like:

```
for (var item, key of someArray) { ... }
```

Answer (score 465, accepted):

[`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) already has this ability:

```
const someArray = [9, 2, 5];
someArray.forEach((value, index) => {
    console.log(index); // 0, 1, 2
    console.log(value); // 9, 2, 5
});
```

But if you want the abilities of `for...of`, then you can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array to the index and value:

```
for (const { index, value } of someArray.map((value, index) => ({ index, value }))) {
    console.log(index); // 0, 1, 2
    console.log(value); // 9, 2, 5
}
```

That's a little long, so it may help to put it in a reusable function:

```
function toEntries<T>(a: T[]) {
    return a.map((value, index) => [index, value] as const);
}

for (const [index, value] of toEntries(someArray)) {
    // ..etc..
}
```

**Iterable Version**

This will work when targeting ES3 or ES5 if you compile with the `--downlevelIteration` compiler option.

```
function* toEntries<T>(values: T[] | IterableIterator<T>) {
    let index = 0;
    for (const value of values) {
        yield [index, value] as const;
        index++;
    }
}
```

**Array.prototype.entries() - ES6+**

If you are able to target ES6+ environments then you can use the [`.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) method as outlined in [Arnavion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36111163/188246).

Comment: But TypeScript compiles "for ... of" to a simple "for" which has an index var _i. So it would be easy for TypeScript developers to let us use this _i. See playground example: bit.ly/1R9SfBR

Comment: @Mick it depends on the target. When transpiling to ES6 it doesn't do that. The reason for that extra code when transpiling is only to get the ES6 code to work in past versions.

Comment: How can you do a break; in that forEach?

Comment: Also a good answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348937/access-to-es6-array-element-index-inside-for-of-loop

Comment: @JoãoSilva you can use `Array.some()` and return false at the iteration you want to stop.  It's not nearly as clear or pretty as a `break` but it would get the job done.  Personally I don't like it, I'd probably re-write the iteration in some other way :) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641347/short-circuit-array-foreach-like-calling-break

Comment: @Neek Yeah, at the time I ended up just throwing an exception and catching it, anyways, it was almost 2 years ago so I have learned a few tricks for it already ;)

Answer (score 89):

See: [Array.prototype.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries)

```
for (const [key, item] of someArray.entries()) { ... }
```

In TS this requires targeting ES2015 [since it requires the runtime to support iterators](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b379e7fc791fc8646d9d255adce5127a6ab83099/lib/lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts#L65), which ES5 runtimes don't. You can of course use something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true&code=var%20someArray%20%3D%20%5B9%2C%202%2C%205%5D%3B%0Afor%20%28var%20%5Bkey%2C%20item%5D%20of%20someArray.entries%28%29%29%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log%28key%2C%20item%29%3B%0A%7D%0A) to make the output work on ES5 runtimes.

Comment: If you target es5, enable `downLevelIteration` explicitly in `tsconfig`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49221814/3850405

Answer (score 67):

"Old school javascript" to the rescue (for those who aren't familiar/in love of functional programming)

```
for (let i = 0; i < someArray.length ; i++) {
  let item = someArray[i];
}
```

Comment: I actually prefer this answer the best. No using of extra methods just to generate an index for each element.

Comment: Thank youuu veryyyy muuuchh! We did not know this :)

Answer (score 20):

You can use the **for..in** TypeScript operator to access the index when dealing with collections.

```
var test = [7,8,9];
for (var i in test) {
   console.log(i + ': ' + test[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
 0: 7
 1: 8
 2: 9
```

See [Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20test%20%3D%20%5B7%2C8%2C9%5D%3B%0D%0Afor%20(var%20i%20in%20test)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(i%20%2B%20'%3A%20'%20%2B%20test%5Bi%5D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A)

Comment: Be aware that "i" is a string not an int with for..in loop. Performing arithmetic operation with "i" will result in string concatenation. (i + 1) will be equal to "01" for example when i = 0

Comment: `for..in` can also give you more than you were expecting as it includes all functions declared on an object as well. For example: `for (var prop in window.document) { console.log(prop); }`

Answer (score 11):

Or another old school solution:

```
var someArray = [9, 2, 5];
let i = 0;
for (var item of someArray) {
    console.log(item); // 9,2,5
    i++;
}
```