# TypeScript: implementation of [Symbol.iterator]: why it doesn't work on unit test (Karma + Jasmine?

Tags: typescript

My interface defines the iterator:

```
[Symbol.iterator]() : IterableIterator<IDocument>;
```

My class `DocumentManager` implements this interface:

```
*[Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<IDocument>{
    for(let n of this._documents){// this._documents is Array<IDocument>
        yield n;
    }
}
```

In debug mode I see `this._documents` has three documents, but this code doesn't iteration:

```
let m = 0;
for(let n of app.documentManager){
    ++m;
}
// here m == 0 still...
```

So the iteration doesn't happen. What I did wrong?

**UPD**

For example, it works in JavaScript:

```
let collection = {
    items : ['a','b','c','d','e'],
    *[Symbol.iterator](){
        for(let item of this.items){
            yield item;
        }
    }
};

for(let n of collection){
    console.log(n);
}
```

Why I have the problem with TypeScript?

**UPD2**

Oh, now I see it doesn't work only on the unit test (`Karma` + `Jasmine`) but works fine in `Node.js`. But I need my unit tests work too.... :(((

Comment: Could you post your `tsconfig.json`, typescript version, and any command line flags you are passing to `tsc`? Some of the links I posted in the answer have specific flags and exclude certain emit levels.

Comment: @SeanNewell, I posted my code example on GitHub here: https://github.com/Andrey-Bushman/webstorm-using . My test '#Iterator iterates the documents.' is failed.

Comment: Your JS example works in Typescript (as it should), let me try and write a class that compiles to something similar...

Comment: In my project, it is `DocumentManager` class.

Comment: Got something working :D Both with/without type explicit annotations on the iterator. Editing my answer...

Comment: I'm gonna try and add an interface like yours and make sure it still works.

Comment: Yeah adding an interface that defines the `Symbol.iterator` method still works. Doesn't even need to have `*`, as the `IterableIterator` return type takes care of that, I'll amend my code sample.

Comment: If I add the `*` into the interface then it will not compile. I have tried to do it. :(

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what you did wrong, but here is some typescript code that compiles and runs fine:

```
interface IterateNum {
  [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<number>;
}

class Collection implements IterateNum {
    private items = [1,2,3,4]; // can be Array<T>

    constructor() {}

    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
        for(let i of this.items) {
            yield i;
        }
    }
}

for(let n of (new Collection())) {
    console.log(n);
}
```

I wrote the above code, and copied your `tsconfig.json` and running `tsc` and `node dist/file.js` works fine. Something else is likely wrong with your code. Try writing a minimal, standalone script to get the pieces you are interested in working together, and isolate call sites.

---

Notes about this feature set in general:

You need to implement the interface (the `next` function), not just yield values. [This online gitbook does a good job on how to implement an interator in TS](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/iterators.html).

[Here's a related PR that describes more details of the TS implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12346).

There's some wonkiness with the `for-of` down-level emitting, so make sure your tsconfig is set up properly. ([target es6, as per this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11209))

Note - worth mentioning [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36108402/2378943), the question is slightly different, but the linked answer talks explicitly about an Iterable version that looks more like what this OP is looking for.

Comment: @AndreyBushman it is worth noting that I have `node v8.5.0` installed, not sure what else it could be since your typescript version/config seems in order.

Comment: my node version is v8.6.0

Comment: I added **UPD 2** section.

Comment: Interesting update - I don't know enough to guide you more, perhaps try to investigate `karma-typescript` and see if it isn't respecting your `es6` compiler option?

Comment: I installed `karma-typescript-es6-transform` and add that info into the `carma.conf.ts` file but the problem exists still.