# TypeScript and Iterator: Type 'IterableIterator<T>' is not an array type

Tags: typescript

When I use the [`yield*` expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield*) on TypeScript, it always gets an error.

> Type 'IterableIterator' is not an array type.

How can I set the types correctly without using `any` to avoid the errors?

```
function* g1(): IterableIterator<number> {
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
  yield 4;
}

function* g2(): IterableIterator<number> {
  yield 1;
  // ERROR: Type 'IterableIterator<number>' is not an array type.
  yield* g1();
  yield 5;
}

const iterator = g2();
```

Answer (score 229, accepted):

If possible update target to `es2015` (or above) in the tsconfig to resolve the error without enabling down level iteration`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015"
  }
}
```

If you target es5, enable `downLevelIteration` explicitly in the tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "downlevelIteration": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason this is not by default?

Comment: @Ben I remember reading in some GitHub issue that the team was not particularly happy about the fact that the generated code is UGLY and does not really fit in with the TS design goal of generating readable JS ..

Comment: irony! The old school `for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` is every bit readable than any (of these showoff) `for-of` arrays :)

Comment: If you work with VSC, just restart it for the changes to take place

Comment: @Kariamoss yes, sometimes unfortunately restating is needed. "The Restart ts server" command is also a good option to restart just the ts language service

Comment: Or alternatively (implied but not explicitly stated), set the target to "es6".

Comment: @CraigFisher Yes, that is a very good observation, I will add it to the answer, the `downlevelIteration` is only required for if `for of` is not natively supported

Comment: I am already having `"target": "es2015"` in my tsconfig, still getting error, any inputs? I am not sure if I should change it. will changing it will break some other things in the code?

Comment: I'm getting this error, although I have `"downlevelIteration": true,` and `"target": "es5"` in my tsconfig.json file. But it's launching Karma that throws the error. A simple "tsc" produces no error.

Answer (score -11):

```
tsc demo.ts --lib "es6","dom" --downLevelIteration
```

Use this command for compilation. It will solve the issue. Adding these values in tsconfig.json will not solve the problem, if tsconfig.json is created with target:es5. updating tsconfig.json manually will not work. Use this command, just change the name of your .ts file.

Comment: If adding the downlevelIteration parameter to your tsconfig.json file did not solve the problem, something is wrong. Perhaps you modified the wrong tsconfig.json file? Or perhaps the parameter was overridden in an inheriting tsconfig?