# Cypress+TS: Get text from HTMLelement

Tags: typescript, get, browser-automation, cypress

I am working with:

Cypress.io and TypeScript.

I faced logical issue.

What I want **to do**:

There are list of elements in few pages. I want to take that list of elements and check if they have some kind of name and if one of these have that name, open it.
I have faced with such problem, that I cannot take text from HTML element. This is my code:

```
it.only('should be able to open element', function () {
 cy.get('.page-number').each(function () { // Using this to get all pages 
    cy.get('div[class="name"] > a > u').then(elem => { //Here I get elements with job names
      console.log('1 ', elem.get(0)); //RESULT: only that one element name. Example:<u _ngcontent-c10="">Element 1</u>
      console.log('2 ', elem.text()); //RESULT: all elements in a page as text
      const textElem = elem.get(1); 
      let txt = +textElem;
      console.log('3 ', textElem); //RESULT: tried to convert it like this. Example:<u _ngcontent-c10="">Element 1</u>
      console.log('4 ', elem.get(0).text()); //RESULT: Error Message: TS2339: Property 'text' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
      let i = 0;
      const jobName = elem.get(i);
      console.log('3 ', elem.get(i));
    if({HERE I WANT TO GET ELEMENT TEXT} === 'My text'){
      //TODO
     }
       else{
          if(expect(i).to.be.oneOf([8, 16, 24])){ //one page have 8 elements
          cy.get('.page-number').click({multiple : true}); //one another page with elements
          cy.log('ELEMENT WAS NOT FIND IN PAGE.');
          }
         i++;
       }
    });
  });
})
```

**Question:**
How I can get HTMLelement text in this situation?
Or I might use to difficult logic in this? If yes, please give me an idea, how it can be solved better.

Comment: @emery you deleted a good chunk of Vilius' original code, which makes things quite confusing (the original had reference to selecting multiple elements). If you wish to illustrate a different scenario, please post (and answer) a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the basic problem is that `.each()` iterates the list of found elements, so inside the `each()` function you only get one element at a time, but the inner code uses `.get()` as if `elem` is an array of elements.

You may find it easier to use `.then(elems => {...})`.

I use array mapping to get an array of the text values using native `textContent` (ref [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)) and the spread operator to convert the result of `cy.get()` to an array that works with `.map()`.

```js
it('should...', () => {
  ...
  cy.get('div[class="name"] > a > u').then(elems => {

    const texts = [...elems].map(el => el.textContent.trim());
    let i = 0;
    if (texts[i] === 'My text') {
      ...
    }
    else {
      ...
    }
});
```

Also `if(expect(i).to.be.oneOf([8, 16, 24]))` is probably not a good idea because `expect` has side effects. I would use a simple boolean expression for example `if([8, 16, 24].includes(i))` and `expect` inside it.

Comment: Thanks.
I removed each(), will think how to deal pages latter.

Took elements in const like in your example + need to add [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218765/typescript-and-iterator-type-iterableiteratort-is-not-an-array-type) that your case would work.

Comment: UPD: I removed each(), when I face another issue. Need to check all elements in a list, because now it take only one element. But this is another issue, witch I hope, I will resolve. :)

Comment: This is an answer to an earlier version of the question.  I edited the question heavily to make it more applicable in a general way, for people who are looking to retrieve text from the inside of a Cypress element

Answer (score 2):

To get an actual string object and not a JQuery object, you can use:

```
cy.get(myElement).then((theElement) => {
  theElement.text() // this returns a string with the element's InnerHTML
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking but if you just want to get the text of an element you can do this.

```
cy.get("Your Selector").invoke('text').then((text) => {
         expect(text.trim()).equal('what ever your text is');
  });
```

If I misunderstood, please comment and I will do my best to answer it.

Comment: This lead me to: TS2339: Property 'trim' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

I am trying to get text from every element in a page. And if these is no such element(text) in page, I want to open next page and try checking next page elements.