# Create a array based on Map

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have one map. Checking consecutive keys values on the map, I need to segregate keys & insert into a new array.

```
let map = new Map<string, string>();
map.set("SUNDAY", "1");
map.set("MONDAY", "2");
map.set("TUESDAY", "2");
map.set("WEDNESDAY", "4");
map.set("THURSDAY", "5");
map.set("FRIDAY", "5");
map.set("SATURDAY", "9");
```

Expected Output should be like this:

```
[{
      day: "SUNDAY",
      value: "1"
    },
    {
      day: "MONDAY-TUESDAY",
      value: "2"
    },
    {
      day: "WEDNESDAY",
      value: "4"
    },
    {
      day: "THURSDAY-FRIDAY",
      value: "5"
    },
    {
      day: "SATURDAY",
      value: "9"
    }
  ];
```

Comment: The question is underspecified as it's unclear how you want to combine days. The example leaves it open whether the aggregated keys are a range (e.g., "Monday-Wednesday") or just a joined array (e.g., "Monday-Tuesday-Wednesday").

Comment: @IngoBürk aggregated keys are a range (e.g., "Monday-Wednesday")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) of the `Map` and group them based on the `value`. If the current `value` is already present in the accumulator, append a `-` and the current `day` to the object. Else, add a new key to the accumulator. Then use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to return the values of the accumulator as an array

```js
const map = new Map([["SUNDAY","1"],["MONDAY","2"],["TUESDAY","2"],["WEDNESDAY","4"],["THURSDAY","5"],["FRIDAY","5"],["SATURDAY","5"]]);

const merged = [...map].reduce((acc, [day, value]) => {
  if(acc[value])
    acc[value].day += `-${day}`
  else
    acc[value] = { day, value };
  
  return acc
}, {});

const output = Object.values(merged);

console.log(output)
```

**Update:**

If typescript doesn't allow you to spread the `Map` inside an array, you can set `downlevelIteration` to `true` in tsconfig ([TypeScript and Iterator: Type 'IterableIterator' is not an array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218765))

You could also use [`Map#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) to do the same thing. Also, if you want the `day` to be a range of days, you could use another variable called 'previousValue'. If the `previousValue` is same as current value, split the `day` which already exists at `-` and take the first value. Then append the current `day`

```js
let map = new Map([["SUNDAY","1"],["MONDAY","2"],["TUESDAY","2"],["WEDNESDAY","4"],["THURSDAY","5"],["FRIDAY","5"],["SATURDAY","5"]]);
let merged = {}, previousValue;

map.forEach((value, day) => {
  if(previousValue === value)
    merged[value].day = `${merged[value].day.split('-')[0]}-${day}`
  else
    merged[value] = { day, value };
  
  previousValue = value;
})

const output = Object.values(merged)

console.log(output)
```

Comment: You missed combining days `MONDAY-TUESDAY` and `THURSDAY-FRIDAY`

Comment: My angular code is giving error like: Type 'Map<string, string>' is not an array type or a string type.

Comment: @Suman which line exactly? If it's the `[...map]` line, try using [...map.entries()]`

Comment: Yes. I already tried with entries. Its giving error like : Type 'IterableIterator<[string, string]>' is not an array type or a string type.

Comment: @Suman You might have to tweak tsconfig to use this [TypeScript and Iterator: Type 'IterableIterator<T>' is not an array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218765) (I'll add an answer which doesn't involve spreading the `Map`)

Comment: @Suman add another option using `.forEach` which doesn't involve spreading the `Map`

Comment: It's working. But Output coming as  {day: "THURSDAY-FRIDAY-SATURDAY", value: "5"} if 3 of the key's values are same. But I want is  {day: "THURSDAY-SATURDAY", value: "5"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191868/discussion-between-suman-and-adiga).