# Type 'IterableIterator<number>' is not an array type or a string type

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, next.js

I am getting the following error when trying to generate a dynamic range of numbers.

`Type 'IterableIterator<number>' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.`

I found an existing question but the solution isn't working for me.

[TypeScript and Iterator: Type 'IterableIterator<T>' is not an array type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49218765/typescript-and-iterator-type-iterableiteratort-is-not-an-array-type/49221814)

My setup is a follows...

- I used the command `npx create-next-app@latest --ts`

```js
class FlexGrid extends React.Component {

    range(size: number, startAt = 0) {
        return [...Array(size).keys()].map(i => i + startAt);
    }
```

I have tried setting `target: es6` and `downlevelIteration: true` neither resolve the error.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: If I build that code with `tsc -p .`  in a folder that contains a file with your code and a tsconfig with the config you posted I get no errors. Are you sure the tsconfig is being picked up?

Comment: Where do you see this error? The code you posted doesn't report any errors on typescript playground.

Comment: @Titan -- no I am not sure... but since I just used the command `npx create-next-app@latest --ts` and everything in the project was autogenerated I don't see how that would be the case

Comment: @tromgy -- I see this error when running `npm run build` which maps to the command `next build`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it is being strict and doesn't want to create an array using spread from an iterator (which is not an array). However it's possible to create an array from an iterator using the `Array.from` function:

```
range(size: number, startAt = 0) {
  return Array.from(Array(size).keys()).map((i) => i + startAt);
}
```

`Array.from` accepts `Iterable`.