# can't get for..of loop working in typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a custom iterables in VS Code with TypeScript. It won't iterate at all through it. What am I doing wrong? I've set the target to `es6` and tried with and without downlevel generation flag.

```
// this works
test("can iterate array", () => {
    let total = 0;
    for (let i of [1, 2, 3]) {
        total = total + i;
    }
    expect(total).toBe(6);
});

function* numbers() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
}

let myInterable = {
    [Symbol.iterator]: numbers
};

// this does NOT work
test("can iterate custom", () => {
    let total = 0;
    for (let i of myInterable) {
        total = total + i;
    }
    expect(total).toBe(6);
});
```

This is the relevant part of my tsconfig.json...

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "esnext",
  "target": "es6",
  "lib": [
    "es6",
    "dom"
  ],
  "sourceMap": true,
  "allowJs": true,
  "jsx": "react",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "rootDir": "src",
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "noImplicitReturns": true,
  "noImplicitThis": true,
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "strictNullChecks": true,
  "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
  "noUnusedLocals": false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript for ... of with index / key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108110/typescript-for-of-with-index-key)

Comment: I also tried the more simple ` for (let i of numbers())`, avoiding the whole symbol thing, and that doesn't work either

Comment: even more simpler: for (let i of { [Symbol.iterator]: function* () { yield 1; yield 2; yield 3; } }) {
    console.log(i);
}

Comment: does it have anything to do with browser compatibility?

Comment: just figured out that this iterator stuff works in the web browser but it is not working in my jest tests. somehow i have to figure out how to get jest to use es6.

Answer (score 0):

I had to restart VS Code. All the tests below pass.

```
test("can iterate array", () => {
    let total = 0;
    for (let i of [1, 2, 3]) {
        total = total + i;
    }
    expect(total).toBe(6);
});

function* numbers() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
}

test("can iterate custom", () => {
    let total = 0;
    for (let i of numbers()) {
        total = total + i;
    }
    expect(total).toBe(6);
});

test("can iterate custom iterable", () => {
    let x = {
        [Symbol.iterator]: numbers
    };
    let total = 0;
    for (let i of x) {
        total = total + i;
    }
    expect(total).toBe(6);
});
```

And in package.json...

"target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],