# How to get the key value when using for await...of

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I would like to get the `key` information  in my `for await...of` loop:

```js
for await (const user of users) {
  const userData= await fetchUserData(user.id)
}
```

But I get the error `.for is not iterable` when I do it like this:

```js
for await (const [key, user] of users) {
  console.log(`fetching user ${key} out of ${users.length} users`)
  const userData= await fetchUserData(user.id)
}
```

Is there a way to get the information about `key` in my loop ?

Comment: what is `users`?

Comment: If `users` is an object it can't be mapped. For retrieve `[key, value]` tupple, you should map `Object.entries`

Comment: It can't be an object, it needs to at least be async iterable

Comment: `users` is an array of objects

Comment: If it is an array of objects, why do you use `for await` at all? If you just want the index in a `for ... of` loop over an array, you may want to check e.g. [access-to-es6-array-element-index-inside-for-of-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348937/access-to-es6-array-element-index-inside-for-of-loop)

Comment: The first code example works very well, my goal with getting the key was to know at which iteration I'm at to have a visual hint during the process

Comment: The link fixes my issue with `.entries()`, you can post it as an answer if you want

Comment: `for await` can iterate sync iterables as well, so it "works", but the reason this isn't directly closed as dupe of above question is imho, because the `for await` implies async iterables, where a "key" (or index) doesn't even need to exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for await...of` works like `for of` and needs to specify `.entries()` to get the key like this:

```js
for await (const [key, user] of users.entries()) {
  console.log(key, user);
}
```