# How can I keep track of array index with for...of loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

This is the object:

```js
const game = {
  team1: 'Bayern Munich',
  team2: 'Borrussia Dortmund',
  players: [
    [
      'Neuer',
      'Pavard',
    ],
    [
      'Burki',
      'Schulz',
    ],
  ],
  score: '4:0',
  scored: ['Lewandowski', 'Gnarby', 'Lewandowski', 'Hummels'],
  date: 'Nov 9th, 2037',
  odds: {
    team1: 1.33,
    x: 3.25,
    team2: 6.5,
  },
};
```

I want use `for..of` and keep track of array index while looping.

Possible solution:

```js
for (const [i, player] of game.scored.entries())
  console.log(`Goal ${i + 1}: ${player}`);
```

Or:

```js
let i = 0
for(const game1 of game.scored) {
  i++;
  console.log(i,game1)
}
```

But is it possible to declare any variable in for statement and keep track of it?

Thank you.

Comment: why nor take standard `for`?

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34348937/access-to-es6-array-element-index-inside-for-of-loop

Answer (score 3):

You can't. But you have these four alternatives:

```js
const arr = ['apple', 'banana', 'carrot']

for (const i in arr) { console.log(i, arr[i]) }
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { console.log(i, arr[i]) }
for (const [i, elt] of arr.entries()) { console.log(i, elt) }
arr.forEach((elt, i) => console.log(i, elt))
```