# Typecheck before loop ignored inside loop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typechecking

In a React component I have something similar to:

```
  if (props.someArray){  // typecheck because someArray is of type 'things[] | undefined'
    props.someArray.forEach((element, i) => {      
        someFunction(i, element, props.someArray); // error despite typecheck (due to "| undefined")
    });    
  }

  // The functions someArray argument's type is only 'things[]', not 'things[] | undefined'
  const someFunction = (i: number, element: thing, someArray: things[]) => {
     someArray[i] = // do some stuff;
  }
```

Since the typecheck is already done before the loop, is it really necessary to do it again before calling the function inside the loop? (inconveniently checking on every iteration instead of just once before looping).

```
  if (props.someArray){  // <- I'd like to keep just this
        props.someArray.forEach((element) => {    
            if (props.someArray) { // <- is this really necessary?
                someFunction(element, props.someArray);
            }
        });    
      }
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach` uses a closure, and TypeScript is cautious about how type-information passes between function boundaries. If you use `for(of)` instead then you won't have any problems because it doesn't use a closure.

Comment: Also, consider changing `someArray: things[]` to `someArray: readonly things[]`, as readonly arrays support array-element-type covariance but mutable arrays don't.

Comment: Thanks! Time to read some theory because it's the first time I hear about "covariance". Also, I am only refactoring all of this just trying to optimize a sluggish canvas animation, and reading on `for...of` I see it's less performant than `for.Each`. Any guess if if would be worth it just to remove that looping if/typecheck? It's the first time I have to do front-end optimization and I am honestly not sure of how to measure these things.

Comment: I'm not aware of any credible arguments for `forEach` somehow being faster than `for(of)` - I remember there was some controversy over performance when the feature was added around 2014 but I haven't heard anything since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Array.prototype.forEach` uses a closure (i.e. an entirely separate `function`) for the loop body, and TypeScript is cautious about how type-information passes between function boundaries.

  - Namely because TypeScript has no way of knowing how `forEach` will invoke the callback because any script can simply overwrite or replace the default `Array.prototype.forEach` implementation and do something silly, like repeatedly invoke the function on only the first element or something.
- If you use `for(of)` instead then you won't have any problems because it doesn't use a closure: as it's a native language construct the TypeScript *type engine* <sub>(is that a word?)</sub> can reason about it more than it can with `.forEach`.
- Other reasons to use `for(of)` instead of `forEach`:

  - You can use `await` inside `for(of)`.
  - You can use `break` to abort a loop (you can't abort a `forEach` without using `throw`).
  - It works with *any* iterable, whereas `forEach` is only available on certain specific collection types (`Array`, `NodeList`, and a few others).

So change your code to this:

```js
if ( props.someArray ) {

    for( const el of props.someArray ) {

        someFunction( el, props.someArray );
    }
}
```

If you want to get both the array-element and its index inside the `for` loop [then use `entries()` like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34349737/159145):

```js
if ( props.someArray ) {

    for( const [idx, el] of props.someArray.entries() ) {

        someFunction( idx, el, props.someArray );
    }
}
```