# addEventListener("click",...) firing immediately

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create some appropriately-placed instructional tooltips that users click through to understand how the site interface works. Each tooltip has a "next" link that toggles the visibility of the previous and next tooltips by modifying the classes (and hence, css).

Here's some simplified code that is supposed to do this:

```
function displayTooltip(t){
  //...some code to determine the tooltip IDs "next" and "previous"
  document.getElementById(previous).className = "tooltip invisibleTooltip";
  document.getElementById(next).className = "tooltip";
}

document.getElementById("tooltip-link1").addEventListener("click", displayTooltip(2));
```

`displayTooltip` is called immediately (and correctly toggles the class) when I paste this code into the console (or on page load). If I replace `displayTooltip` with an `alert()`, it fires when I click, as anticipated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: when you say 

document.getElementById("tooltip-link1").addEventListener("click", displayTooltip(2));

you are invoking the method there only and hence it is executing immediately

Comment: Change `displayTooltip(2)` to `displayTooltip.bind(null, 2)`. For explanation see below answers.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

When you are binding event you are `calling` the function `document.getElementById("tooltip-link1").addEventListener("click",displayTooltip(2));`

You need to pass reference to the function.

Change to below

```
document.getElementById("tooltip-link1").addEventListener("click", function(){
   displayTooltip(2)
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation on the difference between calling and passing the reference made what was happening understandable (I thought addEventListener accepted references, not functions themseves).

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. No tutorial explains this.

Comment: Thank you so much I have been looking all over the internet for this!!!!

Answer (score 28):

When you write `functionName` followed by `()`, it will call function. If you wish to assign function to a handler, you should do

```
document.getElementById("tooltip-link1").addEventListener("click", displayTooltip);
```

Now if you wish to pass parameter to this function, you can either wrap it inside a function like

```
document.getElementById("tooltip-link1")
  .addEventListener("click", function(){displayTooltip(2)});
```

Or you can use `.bind()`

```
document.getElementById("tooltip-link1")
  .addEventListener("click", displayTooltip.bind(this, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call this method as a callback. Since you are calling it as displayTooltip(2) you are ultimately calling the function at that line.

What you need to do is to bind a callback rather than calling at that line. 
Something like

```
 .addEventListener('event', function()
     { displayTooltip(2) }
```

Hope this be of some help

Happy Learning