# What difference does it make to invoke a function inside then?

Tags: javascript, promise

Here is the snapshot of code that I am trying to run

I am not getting why is it returning different results in both the cases 
and
How is it adding the resolved string in the PromiseValue of the promise object that is returned.

[image: promise in devtools]

Comment: `asdf` is passing a function reference. `asdf()` is a function call.

Comment: "Here is how to fold clothes. When the washing machine finishes, fold the laundry like I showed you" vs "Let me fold all clothes and then run the washing machine".

Comment: I had written an answer long back. That might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35667349/3783478. Yes the linked answer does not use promise but has fundamentally same solution