# Javascript addEventListener Callback logic

Tags: javascript, callback, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am following a Javascript video tutorial in which we are learning about event- listeners. We coded the following small web app that lets you input elements on a list:

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");

//Apparently if it is just one parameter it just gets transferred
function inputLength()
{
    return input.value.length;
}

//If there is just one parameter it gets transferred
function createListElement()
{
    var li = document.createListElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
}

// Making sure that it does not add empty strings
function addListAfterClick()
{
    if(inputLength() > 0)
    {
        createListElement();
    }
}

//Making sure that it just adds after pressing enter
function addListAfterKeypress(event)
{
    if(inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13)
    {
        createListElement();
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

I am confused on why the functions were called this way:

```
button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);
```

Instead of this way:

```
button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick());
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress(event));
```

I know that it has something to do with callback functions. However, I am still unsure of how it just automatically gets the values of the parameters just like of art of magic.

Comment: Because then the function would be called immediately, rather than being passed as a callback. eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667267/addeventlistenerclick-firing-immediately

Answer (score 1):

The function is called like this because of the syntax rule of event listener which goes like this

```
element.addEventListener(event, function, useCapture);
```

whenever we are using an event listener you need to add function without `()` because by using `()` will make the function run before your event click happen which you don't want.

So right way is this:

`button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);`

and

`input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress(event));`

is wrong because now function inside `addListAfterKeypress` don't need to access event it used above and only used whenever you need to tell the browser which key will activate this function by the help of keycode

Comment: So by not putting () at the end of the function name a reference is sent and the parameters are automatically sent somehow?

Answer (score 0):

When you add an event listener, you bind the specific event to a function. It's like saying to the browser "Hey, whenever a click event happens on the button element, remember to execute the `addListAfterClick` function". In order to do that, you just need to specify the name of the function that needs to be invoked when that event happens. If you add the `()` at the end of the function name, you will invoke it immediately (run it) instead of saving it as a reference (callback) to be called in the future.

Comment: I think you should go through [this introduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to get a better understanding of events.

Answer (score 0):

javascript save it for later because that i how eventlistener inside JavaScript work 
if your write function inside eventlistener with `()` then it will execute as normal function do

Answer (score 0):

Function `addListAfterKeypress()` have already done its work above you don't need to add

parameter inside eventlistener because it don't want parameters eventlistener is just executing the output from `addListAfterKeypress()`from above which is that is a enter key (because keycode is 13)