# Shopify EventListener is not listening

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app

```
{% javascript %}
window.addEventListener('resize', console.log('Screen size changed!'));
{% endjavascript %}
```

This code is supposed to run whenever screen resolution is changed but it only works once the page is loaded, it does not fire when I change resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens is because you are calling the function right away and therefore the `console.log` only outputs once the page is loaded.

What you would need to do is place this inside of a function like so:

```
{% javascript %}
  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    console.log('Screen size changed!')
  });
{% endjavascript %}
```

That way, whenever the window is resized the function will run and the `console.log` will be output.

A further explanation on why this is happening can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35667286/10390314).