# event listener not working in certain instances - javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am having an issue with Javascript. I have an event listener that activates on button click. It works fine 90% of the time but periodically does not work - or works VERY slowly. This issue seems to happen on Windows machines especially when using Chrome. It (almost) always works fine on Mac.I'm very confused by this issue. Is there anything I can do to fix the code so it stops happening?

I think it may be an issue with typescript, I imported standard javascript into a platform called gorilla that has switched to typescript.

Event listener:

```
againBtn.addEventListener('click', gorilla.finish());
```

error:

Game javascript.ts line 73: Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addEventListener("click",...) firing immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667267/addeventlistenerclick-firing-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using TypeScript and error happens because of `--strictFunctionType` flag enabled. Try calling your `gorila` function from the callback that is declared for `eventListener` function like this:

```
againBtn.addEventListener('click', (event: Event) => gorilla.finish());
```