# Onclick only executing function once

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

So I'm pretty new to js. I've tried to make a button that logs `hey` in the console, but it already logs it before clicking the button. And when clicking the button it won't do anything.  This is my code.

```js
let btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn1.onclick = console.log('hey');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input value="test" type="button" id="btn1" data="onclick">
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to set it to a function: `btn1.onclick = () => console.log('hey');`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addEventListener("click",...) firing immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667267/addeventlistenerclick-firing-immediately)

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
btn1.onclick = console.log('hey');
```

This executes `console.log('hey')` *immediately*, then sets its *result* (which is `undefined`) to `btn1.onclick`;

What you want is a *function* to assign as the click handler.  Also, use `addEventListener` instead of assigning to `onclick`.  For example:

```js
let btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn1.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('hey'));
```

```html
<input value="test" type="button" id="btn1" data="onclick">
```

Or, using the more explicit `function` syntax for potential clarity:

```js
let btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
btn1.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log('hey');
});
```

```html
<input value="test" type="button" id="btn1" data="onclick">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this:

```js
btn1.onclick = () => console.log('hey');
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you try this:

```
    let btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
    btn1.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('hey'));
```