# Show textarea change of value length in element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to count the characters that the user types in the textarea and display that value in a span tag.

I'm receiving this error:
***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')***

```
const prompt = document.querySelector("#floatingTextarea2");
const wordCount = document.querySelector(".word-counter")[0];

prompt.addEventListener("input", updateCount());

function updateCount() {
  const count = this.value.length;
  console.log(count);
  wordCount.innerText = count;
}
```

Comment: [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423) and [addEventListener("click",...) firing immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667267)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems:

1. You are calling `updateCount` *immediately* and pass its return value (`undefined`) to `addEventListener`. Instead you have to pass the function itself by omitting the calling parenthesis:

   ```
    prompt.addEventListener("input", updateCount);
    //                                         ^^
   ```

   You are getting this error because when you call `updateCount` immediately `this` refers to the global object, not the element you want to bind the function to.
2. `querySelector` returns a single element, so you need to remove the `[0]` from your second call:

   ```
   const wordCount = document.querySelector(".word-counter");
   //                                                      ^^
   ```

```js
const prompt = document.querySelector("#floatingTextarea2");
const wordCount = document.querySelector(".word-counter");

prompt.addEventListener("input", updateCount);

function updateCount() {
  const count = this.value.length;
  console.log(count);
  wordCount.innerText = count;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="floatingTextarea2"></textarea>
<p>
Characters: <span class="word-counter"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked:

Added `oninput="updateCount()"` to my textarea

```
<textarea oninput="updateCount()"></textarea>
```

```
const prompt = document.querySelector("#floatingTextarea2");
const wordCount = document.querySelector(".word-counter");

function updateCount() {
  const count = prompt.value.length;
  console.log(count);
  wordCount.innerHTML = count + "/300";
}
```